# Confusion with the definition of a convergent numerical process of integration

Tags: functional-analysis, definition

From Kreyszig's Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications:

> Let $X = C[a,b]$ be the Banach space of all continuous real-valued functions on $J=[a,b]$ with norm defined by $\|x\| = \max_{t \in J} |x(t)|$.
>
> A numerical process of integration is defined as: $(1)$ A set of $n+1$ real numbers $t_0^{(n)}, \dots, t_n^{(n)}$ such that $a \le t_0^{(n)}, \lt \dots \lt t_n^{(n)}$ and $(2)$ a choice of $n+1$ real numbers $\alpha_0^{(n)}, \dots, \alpha_n^{(n)}$ with $$f_n(x) = \sum_k^n \alpha_k^{(n)}x(t_k^{(n)})$$ defined as the numerical process of integration.

Then he defines convergence of a numerical process of integration as:

> $f_n$ is convergent for an $x \in X$ if for that $x$, $$f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$$ where $f$ is defined by $\int_a^b x(t) dt$.

But what does $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n$ mean?  For each $n$ there's a choice of a particular $\alpha$ set and $t$ set.  But what are the conditions for the $\alpha$ and $t$ set for this convergence to happen?  Because to me this could be interpreted as "for ALL $\alpha$ and $t$ sets".

Does this instead mean as $n$ approaches infinity there EXISTS an $\alpha$ and $t$ set where this convergence happens?

Comment: Maybe it would be more clear if the notation $f_n$ were made explicitly dependent on the sequences $\alpha$ and $t$. For each $n$ the $\alpha_n$ is an $n$-tuple $(\alpha_0^{(n)},...,\alpha_n^{(n)})$ and so is $t_n$. The numerical process of integration consists of a fixed pair of sequences of tuples $\alpha$ and $t$ and the sequence $f_n=f_{n,\alpha, t}$ that it defines by the formula above.

Comment: This is imitating/generalizing what is done in [quadrature formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature). For example, in some of these, the sequence $t_n$ are the zeros of the $n$-th degree of certain families of orthogonal polynomials. The sequence $\alpha_n$ is computed such that the $f_n(x)$ is exactly the integral for $x$ polynomials of degree smaller than $2n-1$ or so.

Comment: So it’s saying as $n$ approaches infinity there exists an $\alpha$ and $t$ that satisfy the convergence definition?

Comment: No, the sequences of tuples $\alpha$ and $t$ are fixed beforehand. It is saying that that choice of sequences give a sequence of functionals $f_n$ that for the function $x$ in question $f_n(x)$ converges to the integral of $x$.

Comment: I think that you are expecting this concept to work like how Riemann sums are used to define the integral. However, it is not that, it is generalizing what quadrature formulas do. Take a look at the linked article and familiarize yourself with that classical topic and then it will be clear.

Comment: Ah I see now, I misunderstood that for each $n$ there's a predefined sequence.  It makes sense that it would converge now because you'd be increasing the value of $n$ and choosing the next $\alpha, t$ in the sequence.

Comment: They are defining convergence, not claiming that it will happen. For example, if I take the 'numerical process of integration' defined by some fixed sequence of $t$ and but I choose $a_n^{(k)}=0$ for all $n,k$. Then $f_n(x)=0$. This means that the numerical process of integration will converge only for those functions that have integral $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of "numerical process of integration" is missing a crucial part: it should say that *for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$* you have numbers $t^{(n)}_0, \dots t^{(n)}_n$ and $\alpha^{(n)}_0,\dots,\alpha^{(n)}_n$ with the stated properties.  So, a single numerical process of integration consists of a *specific choice* of $\alpha$'s and $t$'s for each $n$ and so defines a specific function $f_n$ on $X$ for each $n$.  We then say this specific numerical process of integration converges for $x$ if $f_n(x)\to f(x)$.